# Validation URL resources for REST API

Tags: rest

Given the following url:

```
http://localhost:port/books/[:id]
```

where `[:id]` represent the book id.

Would it be wise to check if the id value is null or empty?

What I understand is that the each url is unique which will bring users to a specific destination. Thus there is no need to even validate the `[:id]`.

So let's say that I validated [:id].

I have another url that is suppose to list all the books

```
http://localhost:port/books
```

Isn't it conflicting?

Comment: Rule #1 never trust input's from outside the application.

So you will want to check that it is not empty/null, and is actually the correct format for an id, and return an appropriate error message if they are not.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I updated my post. so if i validate my input won't it be conflicting?

Comment: In that case you are still checking for it being empty, and you return a list instead of an item.  So not returning an error in that scenario.  But you still have to code for it, unless the framework you are doing does it for you automatically.

Comment: In a true REST architecture clients would only use links a server provided them with, think of links contained in HTML pages. Unfortunately the world isn't perfect and a malicious client may attempt to invoke "unexpected" URLs, hence a check isn't a bad idea in general.

Comment: @RomanVottner would it be wise to throw a specific error, i.e. like in this case, `invalid book id`. Or would it be better to actually just throw `Not Found`

Comment: If you want to add a new book via POST, the semantic of the payload is defined by the server so wether you decline a payload in presence of a given ID is up to you. Even on updating a resource via PUT the server is allowed to transform the payload to a media-type that fits the current resource representation format, simply replace the current content with the provided one or decline it. The spec states explicitly that it should validate the content against the resource' own constraints. If a client wants to retrieve or delete a resource that doesn't exist it should return a 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be conflicting since a call to

```
http://localhost:port/books/  # Notice the last slash
```

is different to

```
http://localhost:port/books
```

and they will be received by different controller methods.

For example, in Java:

```java
@GET
@Path("/resources/{id}/")
public Resource getResource(@PathParam("id") long id);

@GET
@Path("/resources")
public List<Resource> getAllResources();
```

As we can see, the first method for retrieving a resource is mapped on `/resources/{id}`.

In the other hand, the second method for retrieving all resources is mapped on `/resources`. Which is a different end-point in the API.

If you call the first method with an empty `id`, the API won't be able to find the requested resource (since its null). This NPE should be treated somehow in your back-end and return an according response to the front-end.

You can check this complete [guide about RESTful](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/) developments

Comment: This answer seems highly specific to some kind of Java framework, but the question seems more generic.